# What do you see in an inkspot? Rorschach generation'

Tags: popularity-contest, graphical-output

So I'd like you to attempt to generate Rorschach images like the below image:

[image: Fake Rorschach Picture]

Here is a [link](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/Rorschach_inkblot_test) to further inspiration.

This is a popularity contest, but I will say that colours are likely to be more popular than black and white, as well as textures.

Rorschach images are created by folding paper with ink on so one criteria is symmetry.

ASCII art is valid, but will be subject to the same criteria as above.

Comment: so which is it, code-golf, or popularity-contest?

Comment: @DavidWilkins Thanks, not with it today. Apologies

Comment: <quote Richard Feynman>There's a meaningless  inkblot, and the  others ask you  what you think you see, but when you tell them, they start arguing with you!</quote>

Comment: I see the face of an alien what does that mean?

Comment: Already here :) http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/4224/193

Comment: I would love to see a [stereogram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stereogram) for this.

Comment: It reminded me on a 
[picture](http://www.rouming.cz/roumingShow.php?file=Whats_the_first_thing_that_comes_to_mind.jpg) I saw recently

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Fortran 95

This code is kind of big, but it produces a nice(ish) ASCii result:

```
program Rorschach
implicit none

integer :: i, j, k, l, N, seed
integer, dimension (24) :: i_zero, j_zero
real :: aux
integer, dimension (17,12) :: matrix_I = 0
character, dimension (17,12) :: matrix_C

! random seed according to system clock
call SYSTEM_CLOCK(count=k)
call RANDOM_SEED(size=N)
allocate(seed(N))
seed=k+37*(/ (i - 1, i = 1, n) /)
call RANDOM_SEED(PUT=seed)

! generating 7 random points
do i=1,7
  call RANDOM_NUMBER(aux)
  i_zero(i) = 15 * aux + 2 ! range = 2-16
  call RANDOM_NUMBER(aux)
  j_zero(i) = 11 * aux + 2 ! range = 2-12
enddo

! generating 7 large spots of ink
do i=1,7
  matrix_I(i_zero(i),j_zero(i)) = 3 ! central points have ink value 3
  do k=-1,1
    do l=-1,1
      if (.NOT.((k==0) .AND. (l==0))) then ! immediate neighbours...
        if ( (((i_zero(i)+k)<=17).OR.((i_zero(i)+k)>0)) .AND. (((j_zero(i)+l)<=12).OR.((j_zero(i)+l)>0)) ) then ! ... that are inside the designed area ...
            if (matrix_I(i_zero(i)+k,j_zero(i)+l) < 2) matrix_I(i_zero(i)+k,j_zero(i)+l) = 2 ! ... and that do not have ink value larger than 2 will be attributed as 2
        endif
      endif
    enddo
  enddo
enddo

! generating N little sparkles of ink
call RANDOM_NUMBER(aux)
N = int(11 * aux) + 20 ! N = 20-30

i = 0
do while (i <= N)
  call RANDOM_NUMBER(aux)
  i_zero(i) = 16 * aux + 1 ! range = 1-17
  call RANDOM_NUMBER(aux)
  j_zero(i) = 11 * aux + 1 ! range = 1-12
  if (matrix_I(i_zero(i),j_zero(i)) < 1) then ! if the selected point already has more ink than 1, then cycle the loop
    matrix_I(i_zero(i),j_zero(i)) = 1
    else
      cycle
  endif
  i = i + 1
enddo

! converting matrix of integers into matrix of characters
do i=1,17
  do j=1,12
    select case(matrix_I(i,j))
      case(0)
      matrix_C(i,j) = " "
      case(1)
      matrix_C(i,j) = "."
      case(2)
      matrix_C(i,j) = "+"
      case(3)
      matrix_C(i,j) = "@"      
    end select
  enddo
enddo

! printing it on the screen + its reflection
do i=1,17
  do j=1,12
    write(*,"(A1)",advance="NO") matrix_C(i,j)
  enddo
  do j=12,2,-1
    write(*,"(A1)",advance="NO") matrix_C(i,j)
  enddo
  write(*,"(A1)") matrix_C(i,1)
enddo

end program Rorschach
```

The code is fully commented, but the basic idea is that it generates a matrix with values between 0 and 3, representing the amount of ink in that spot. There are 7 large spots of ink (a spot with a value 3 surrounded by values 2) and a lot of little "sparkles" (value 1). This matrix is then converted into a character matrix, using the following conversion:

```
0 =  
1 = .
2 = +
3 = @
```

Here is a result:

```
 +++      .  .      +++ 
 +@++++   .  .   ++++@+ 
 ++++@+.        .+@++++ 
   .+++   ++++   +++.   
          +@@+          
. .   . +++@@+++ .   . .
.       +@++++@+       .
     ++++++  ++++++     
     +@+        +@+     
.    ++++      ++++    .
   .  +@+      +@+  .   
  .  .+++.    .+++.  .  
 . .   .        .   . . 
    .    .    .    .    
   .   ..      ..   .   
 .                    .
```

Comment: FORTRAN! A personal favourite.

Comment: Thank you! Usually Fortran + beginner's code don't stand a chance here, but boy, have I been learning a lot about programming since I started participating in this site!

Comment: !FORTRAN is king of lists in my eyes, and this is just lists so I don't see how you could go wrong.

Comment: Fortran isn't so hot for brevity, but the performance is on point.

Answer (score 12):

### Python

Not quite the best or smoothest, but here's a python solution:

```
from PIL import Image
import random
import sys

imgsize = (int(sys.argv[1]), int(sys.argv[2]))
color = (0, 0, 0)
img = Image.new("RGB", imgsize, "white")

for j in range(0,int(sys.argv[3])):
    start = (random.randrange(0, imgsize[0]/2), random.randrange(0, imgsize[1]))
    point = start
    img.putpixel(point, color)

    blotsize = random.randrange(0, int(sys.argv[4]))
    for i in range(blotsize):
        directions = [(point[0], point[1]+1), (point[0], point[1]-1), (point[0]+1, point[1]), (point[0]-1, point[1])]
        toremove = []
        for direction in directions:
            if direction[0]>=(imgsize[0]/2) or direction[1]>=imgsize[1] or direction[0]<0 or direction[1]<0:
                toremove.append(direction)
        for d in toremove:
            directions.remove(d)
        point = random.choice(directions)
        img.putpixel(point, color)

cropped = img.crop((0, 0, imgsize[0]/2, imgsize[1]))
img = img.transpose(Image.FLIP_LEFT_RIGHT)
img.paste(cropped, (0, 0, imgsize[0]/2, imgsize[1]))

img.save("blot.png")
```

It just makes a "wandering path" for a blot, and makes several of those.

An example usage:

```
py inkblot.py width height blots blotsize
py inkblot.py 512 512 20 10000
```

And some example images:
[image: blot1] [image: blot2]

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! We encourage posters to make a prominent header indicating the language they used. You can use Markdown syntax in the editor to do so, e.g. `## Python`

Comment: Maybe instead of single pixels you can use (random sized) disks.

Comment: Welcome! You have some very nice results here.